# Issues with arrays and matlab coder

Tags: c, arrays, matlab-coder

I've been working on creating c code with  Matlab-coder. I have a function called melfunction that gives an error for line 20 of the code below.

```
function [ c ] = melfunction( x )

bank=melbankm(24,256,8000,0,0.4,'t');  
bank=full(bank); %full() convert sparse matrix to full matrix  
bank=bank/max(bank(:));

w=1+6*sin(pi*[1:12]./12);
w=w/max(w); 
xx=double(x);  
xx=filter([1-0.9375],1,xx); 
xx=enframe(xx,256,80)
p = zeros(1,256); < --------------------- SOLUTION CHANGE TO p = zeros(256)
m = zeros(1,12);  < --------------------- SOLUTION CHANGE TO p = zeros(12)

for i=1:size(xx,1)  
  y=xx(i,:);  
  s=y'.*hamming(256);  
  t=abs(fft(s));
  t=t.^2; 
  p(i,:) = t; < --------------------------- ERROR HERE
  c1=dctcoef*log(bank*t(1:129));  
  c2=c1.*w';  
  m(i,:)=c2;  
end
```

error message looks like this

**Error using melfunction (line 20)
Index exceeds array dimensions. Index value 2 exceeds valid range [1-1] of array p.**

**Error in TESTINPUTS (line 2)
d0=melfunction(x)**

If I come up with an answer I will post it when I find one.

Comment: That line cannot cause that error. Please see: [mcve]

Comment: i've updated full code. I did not add the actual part where it went bad just the variable...... the line of code that I WAS pointing too is where I think I have to change something...... sorry for the confusion

Comment: One or more assumptions about the size and shape of your data is wrong. You've initialized `p` as a row vector and then attempt to address row `2`, which it doesn't have, in the second loop iteration. Thus, your index exceeds the array dimensions.

Comment: @excaza are there any methods that you know of that might fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so  I messed with it a bit and found that I believe I did not know how to correctly initialize p and m .  In an attempt to add these lines of code for another part of Matlab-Coder I initialized the p and m variables incorrectly.  This is the original initialization.

`p = zeros(1,256);
 m = zeros(1,12);`

this is what I changed it too.

```
p = zeros(256);
m = zeros(12);
```